# How to use more than one union on combobox rowsource in Access 2019 64 bit

Tags: ms-access, 32bit-64bit

I am converting a 32 bit Access DB frontend to 64 bit.  We have code that dynamically builds the rowsource for a combobox of ID and Name from linked views based on check boxes selected.  This could result in up to 6 select statements combined with 5 'union' statements.  This works in the 32 bit application, but in 64 bit it crashes Access if more than one union is in the rowsource SQL.  As a test, I have tried putting parens around the first two selects that are unioned, but that did not work.

This code is designed to reduce the number of rows in the dropdown with each keystroke, so the rowsource is rebuilt and requeried with each keystroke.

For example, to look up the name Jones, the first build where clause would be name like 'J%', the 2nd build would be .... like 'Jo%', etc.

The windows system logs have this info for the crash:

```
    Faulting application name: MSACCESS.EXE, version: 16.0.10376.20033, time stamp: 0x60dff893
    Faulting module name: ACECORE.DLL, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x608a909b
    Exception code: 0xc0000005
    Fault offset: 0x00000000000645bf
    Faulting process id: 0x198
    Faulting application start time: 0x01d78325d24d2c03
    Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\MSACCESS.EXE
    Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Office16\ACECORE.DLL
    Report Id: 15ad9d88-d048-48ec-a0e9-1a8897aa7c8a
    Faulting package full name: 
    Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Code Build_RowSrc:

```
  Const cstrProcNm As String = "Build_RowSrc"
  
  Const strStdSQL As String = "select lngPrsnId, strFullNm from vw_StdCrntMtrcCrtSpcl"
  Const strNDSpclStdSQL As String = "select lngPrsnId, strFullNm from vw_cboStdNDSpcl"
  Const strVisMedStdSQL As String = "select distinct lngPrsnId, strFullNm from vw_VisMedStdFullNm"
  Const strApptSQL As String = "select lngPrsnId, strFullNm from vw_cboPrsnAppts"
  Const strGradSQL As String = "select lngPrsnId, strFullNm from vw_cboJHUSOMGraduates"
  Const strCrtSpclSQL As String = "select lngPrsnId, strFullNm from vw_cboCrtSpclErnd"
  Const strUnion As String = " UNION "
  Dim strcboPrsnRowSrc As String
  
  strcboPrsnRowSrc = ""
  
  strWhere = " where strFullNm like '" & strLetterSelected & "%'"
  
  Select Case Me.cboRqstLtrTp
    Case cbyt_RqstLtrTp_Cert
      If Me.chkAppts = True Then
        strcboPrsnRowSrc = strApptSQL & strWhere
      End If
      
      If Me.chkGrad = True Then
        If Len(strcboPrsnRowSrc) > 0 Then
          strcboPrsnRowSrc = "(" & strcboPrsnRowSrc & strUnion & strGradSQL & strWhere & ")" & strUnion & strCrtSpclSQL & strWhere
        Else
          strcboPrsnRowSrc = strGradSQL & strWhere & strUnion & strCrtSpclSQL & strWhere
        End If
      End If
      
      If Me.chkStd = True Then
        If Len(strcboPrsnRowSrc) > 0 Then
          strcboPrsnRowSrc = strcboPrsnRowSrc & strUnion & strStdSQL & strWhere
        Else
          strcboPrsnRowSrc = strStdSQL & strWhere
        End If
      End If
      
      If Me.chkNDSpclStd = True Then
        If Len(strcboPrsnRowSrc) > 0 Then
          strcboPrsnRowSrc = strcboPrsnRowSrc & strUnion & strNDSpclStdSQL & strWhere
        Else
          strcboPrsnRowSrc = strNDSpclStdSQL & strWhere
        End If
      End If
      
      If Me.chkVisMedStd = True Then
        If Len(strcboPrsnRowSrc) > 0 Then
          strcboPrsnRowSrc = strcboPrsnRowSrc & strUnion & strVisMedStdSQL & strWhere
        Else
          strcboPrsnRowSrc = strVisMedStdSQL & strWhere
        End If
      End If
    Case cbyt_RqstLtrTp_JD, cbyt_RqstLtrTp_InsDscnt
      strcboPrsnRowSrc = "select lngPrsnId, strFullNm from vw_RqstLtrStd" & strWhere & _
        " UNION select lngPrsnId, strFullNm from vw_RqstLtrPDoc" & strWhere
    Case cbyt_RqstLtrTp_USMLE
      strcboPrsnRowSrc = "select distinct lngPrsnId, strFullNm from vw_RqstLtrUSMLE" & strWhere
    Case cbyt_RqstLtrTp_GJD, cbyt_RqstLtrTp_InsDscnt
      strcboPrsnRowSrc = "select lngPrsnId, strFullNm from vw_RqstLtrPDoc" & strWhere
  
  End Select
  
  Build_RowSrc = strcboPrsnRowSrc & " order by strFullNm"
```

Called by SetRecordSource (crashes on rowsource assignment when more than 1 union):

```
  Const cstrProcNm As String = "SetRecordSource"
  
  Dim strEntry As String
  Dim strLetterSelected As String
  
  strLetterSelected = Left$(Me.cboPrsn.Text, 1)
  If (strLetterSelected <> mstrLastLetterSelected) Then
    
    If Len(Nz(Me.cboPrsn.Text, "")) > 0 Then
      With Me.cboPrsn
        .SetFocus
        
        .Text = ""
        .RowSource = Build_RowSrc(strLetterSelected)
        .Requery
        
        If .ListCount > 0 Then
          .ListIndex = 0
          .SelStart = 1
          .SelLength = Len(Nz(.Text, "")) 
          .Dropdown
        End If
        Debug.Print Time
      End With
    End If
    mstrLastLetterSelected = strLetterSelected
    
  End If  'Not strLetterSelected = Me.strLastLetterSelected
```

Any guidance is appreciated.

Peg

Comment: Where does it crash? Try _manually_ to assign a simple rowsource having a `union`. Try to import all objects in a new empty database. Run a reinstall of Office 365.

Comment: It crashes on the assignment of rowsource: .RowSource = Build_RowSrc(strLetterSelected).  I did manually apply a rowsource with a single union.  That is how I know that a single union works but more than one crashes.  I am using Office 2019 Professional Plus 64 bit, on which I did a repair.  Thanks for your comment.